# What kind of JOIN should I be using here?

Tags: mysql

I have a quite longer query but I simplified to this:

```
SELECT p.ref, pl.name
FROM tpv_products p
LEFT JOIN tpv_products_languages pl 
ON p.id = pl.tpv_products_id
WHERE pl.tpv_languages_id = 2;
```

These are the tables:

tpv_products:

```
id | ref
--------
1  | ref1
2  | ref2
3  | ref3
```

tpv_products_language:

```
tpv_languages_id | tpv_products_id | name
---------------------------------------------
1                | 1               | Rice
1                | 2               | Corn
1                | 3               | Milk
2                | 1               | Arroz
```

What I get with my query:

```
ref | name
----------
ref1| Arroz
```

What I was expecting:

```
ref | name
----------
ref1| Arroz
ref2| NULL
ref3| NULL
```

I've tried all type of JOINS but can't find the desired result.

Comment: The `where` condition turns your `left join` into an `inner join` because you filter on data in the joined table. If you put the condition in the `on` clause of the join then it will return the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add condition with join `pl.tpv_languages_id = 2`

```
SELECT p.ref, pl.name
FROM tpv_products p
LEFT JOIN tpv_products_languages pl 
ON p.id = pl.tpv_products_id AND pl.tpv_languages_id = 2;
```